# Linq: Splitting each element in List(of String) and Select the required value

Tags: vb.net, linq, split, linq-to-objects

I wanted to parse the below response and select the values. I dont want to select the last line. Can anyone help me how to select the values using LINQ?

"John:55

Kim:77

Kevin:23

[TimeGenerated: 15/12/2011 12:03:45][ResponseTime : 123.45ms]"

```
Dim Response as String

Dim values as System.Collections.Generic.List(of String)(Response.split(vbcrlf))

Dim dbs as New List(of Double)

dbs = from i in values
      Select i.split(":")(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that, if last line always starts with "["

```
Dim dbs = Response.Split(vbCrLf)
         .Where(Function(m) !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m) And !m.StartsWith("["))
         .Select(Function(m) Convert.ToDouble(m.Split(":").Last().Trim())).ToList();
```